# Type error: "not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float"?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I was unable to group the values in column "MinTemp" into 3 groups and update the dataframe.

The values in column "MinTemp" range from -8.2 to 33.9.
I only want to have 3 groups, `<= 10.0 (mintp1)`, `> 10.0 && <= 22.0` (mintp2) and `> 22.0` (mintp3).

```
from collections import Counter

col         = 'MinTemp'

conditions  = [ data_mod[col] > 22.0, (data_mod[col] > 10.0) & (data_mod[col] <= 22.0), data_mod[col] <= 10.0 ]

choices     = [ 'mintp3', 'mintp2', 'mintp1' ]
data_mod["MinTemp"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='neutral')

Counter(MinTemp)
```

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: `data_mod[col]` is actually a string.

Comment: While it doesn't directly address your error - once you've got your numbers as actual numbers, then it looks like [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) could be worth looking at if you ever want to do more complicated ranged binning.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to convert the string values to numeric values allowing comparison:

```
df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col])
```